# rewriting URL using apache rewriterule

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

How can I configure rule to rewrite URL from

https://globalecom1.psic.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet

to

https://dev-accessories.int.com

Both domain names are pointing to same apache server.

Comment: Did you try anything, from [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/214512/redirect-change-urls-or-redirect-http-to-https-in-apache-everything-you-ever)?

Comment: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev\-accessories\.int\.com$`
\n `RewriteRule   ^/$  https://dev-accessories.int.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet  [R,NE]` does the trick, but I want to truncate /webapp/wcs/stores/servlet from the URL. Adding `RewriteRule   ^/(.*)  /webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/$1  [PT,L]`  doesnt work.

Comment: @Dusan I also have other domains pointing to same server like https://dev-parts.int.com and want same effect for them.
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev\-parts\.int\.com$`
`RewriteRule ^/$ https://dev-parts.int.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet [R,NE]`

Comment: Do you want to keep initial URL in users browser address bar or change it to dev-accessories.int.com ?

Comment: change it to dev-accessories.int.com

Comment: @DusanBajic Any feedback on this?

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
RewriteRule ^/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/?(.*) https://dev-accessories.int.com/$1 [R,NE]
```